# Implementation SSO using SAML in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, single-sign-on, saml

I am new to SSO and WCF(C#). I need to implement SSO using SAML in WCF(C#). I dont want to use any third party tools (Ex. componentspace). Please could any one help me out. Thanks a lot.

-Anto

Answer (score 1):

You may need to implement and customize a `SecurityTokenService`.

You can start looking with the samples provided WIF 4.5 [samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/Federation-Metadata-34036040). For detailed explanation of WIF you can take a look at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh291066(v=vs.110).aspx)

You need to understand what is `WS-Trust` and `WS-Federation`.

Also you need to study what are active and passive SecurityTokenService(STS). You can take a look in the samples and try implementing your own provider, that will provide you the Claims in the `SAML` token format of your choice. For security, you can use certificates to sign\encrypt the tokens.

But before that, you need to identify what claims you want based on requirement and than you need to start writing the things.

Hope this helps!